# Closing SqlConnection and SqlCommand c#

Tags: c#, ado.net, garbage-collection, using-statement

In my DAL I write queries like this:

```
using(SQLConnection conn = "connection string here")
{
    SQLCommand cmd = new ("sql query", conn);
    // execute it blah blah
}
```

Now it just occurred to me that I am not explicitly closing the SQLCommand object. Now I know the 'using' block will take care of the SQLConnection object, but will this also take care of the SQLCommand object? If not than I have a serious problem. I would have to put in the 'using' on the SQLCommand on thousands and thousands of lines of code or do a cmd.Close() on hundreds of methods. Please tell me that if putting in the using or closing the command will provide a better memory management of the web app?

Comment: I think this also should be interesting to you: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Data%20access%20layer%20%28ORM%29%20with%20the%20Value%20Injecter&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the `using` statement will not take care of the command.

You should wrap the commands with `using` statements as well, since this will properly call `Dispose` on them:

```
using(SQLConnection conn = 'connection string here')
{
    using(SQLCommand cmd = new ('sql query', conn))
    {
        //execute it blah blah
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The `SqlConnection` has no knowledge about the `SqlCommand`, so you should close it by itself:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sql query", conn))
{
    // execute it blah blah
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It won't handle the `SqlCommand`, but the `SqlCommand` will *eventually* be handled by the garbage collector.  I tend to do the following:

```
using (SqlConn conn ... )
using (SqlComm comm ... )
{
    conn.Open();
}
```

Stacking the using statements here will handle both.